# Android database error: The literal 2286719584 of type int is out of range.?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

When I put in a phone number I believe it is to big for an int by one digit, but when I ry to change it to anything else it still does not work. says The literal 2286719584 of type int is out of range.

package com.mike.Make2;

public class User {

```
//private variables 
int _phone; 
String _fname; 
String _lname; 

// Empty constructor 
public User(){ 

} 
// constructor 
public User(int phoneid, String fname, String lname){ 
    this._phone = phoneid; 
    this._fname = fname; 
    this._lname = lname; 
} 

// constructor 
public User(String fname, String lname){ 
    this._fname = fname; 
    this._lname = lname; 
} 
// getting phone ID 
public int getPhoneID(){ 
    return this._phone; 
} 

// setting phone id 
public void setPhoneID(int phoneid){ 
    this._phone = phoneid; 
} 

// getting first name 
public  String getFirstName(){ 
    return this._fname; 
} 

// setting first name 
public void setFirstName(String fname){ 
    this._fname = fname; 
} 

// getting last name
public String getLastName(){ 
    return this._lname; 
} 

// setting first name 
public void setLastName(String lname){ 
    this._lname = lname; 
}
```

}

package com.mike.Make2;

```
import android.content.ContentValues; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; 

public class UserDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

    // All Static variables 
    // Database Version 
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 

    // Database Name 
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "makingtime"; 

    // User table name 
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user"; 

    // User Table Columns name 
    private static final String KEY_ID = "phone_number"; 
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "fname"; 
    private static final String KEY_NAME2 = "lname";            


    public UserDatabase(Context context) { 
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
    } 

    // Creating Tables 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase us) { 
        String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_NAME2 + " TEXT" + ")"; 
        us.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE); 
    } 

    // Upgrading database 
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase us, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
        // Drop older table if existed 
        us.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER); 

        // Create tables again 
        onCreate(us); 
    } 

    // Adding new contact to user 
    void addUser(User user) { 
        SQLiteDatabase us = this.getWritableDatabase(); 

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put(KEY_ID, user.getPhoneID()); // contacts phone number
        values.put(KEY_NAME, user.getFirstName()); // Contact first name
        values.put(KEY_NAME2, user.getLastName()); // Contact last name

        // Inserting Row 
        us.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values); 
        us.close(); // Closing database connection 
    } 

    // Getting single contact user
   User getUser(int id) { 
        SQLiteDatabase us = this.getReadableDatabase(); 

        Cursor cursor = us.query(TABLE_USER, new String[] { KEY_ID, 
                KEY_NAME, KEY_NAME2 }, KEY_ID + "=?", 
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null); 
        if (cursor != null) 
            cursor.moveToFirst(); 

        User user = new User(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), 
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2)); 
        // return user
        return user; 
    } 


    // Updating single contact 
    public int updateUser(User user) { 
        SQLiteDatabase us = this.getWritableDatabase(); 

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put(KEY_ID,user.getPhoneID());
        values.put(KEY_NAME, user.getFirstName()); 
        values.put(KEY_NAME2, user.getLastName()); 

        // updating row 
        return us.update(TABLE_USER, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", 
                new String[] { String.valueOf(user.getPhoneID()) }); 
    } 
    public int deleteAll()
    { 
        SQLiteDatabase us = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        return us.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
    }
    public void delete_byPhonenumber(int id)
    { 
        SQLiteDatabase us = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        us.delete(TABLE_USER, KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
    }
    // Deleting single contact 
    public void deleteUser(User user)
    { 
        SQLiteDatabase us = this.getWritableDatabase(); 

        us.delete(TABLE_USER, KEY_ID + " = ?",   new String[] { String.valueOf(user.getPhoneID()) }); 
        us.close(); 
    } 

    // Getting contacts Count 
    public int getUserCount() { 
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER; 
        SQLiteDatabase us = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
        Cursor cursor = us.rawQuery(countQuery, null); 
        cursor.close(); 

        // return count 
        return cursor.getCount(); 
    } 

}
```

package com.mike.Make2;

```
import java.util.List;  
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.widget.TextView; 


public class SQLiteImplement extends Activity { 
    TextView display,display2,display3;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.showdb); 


        display = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvdb1);

        ContactDatabase db = new ContactDatabase(this); 
        UserDatabase us = new UserDatabase(this);
        // Inserting Contacts 
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting .."); 


        db.addContact(new Contact("Michael", "2286970002")); 
        db.addContact(new Contact("David", "2282160000")); 
        db.addContact(new Contact("Brandon", "2286719584")); 

        us.addUser(new User(2286719584,"Michael","Lynn"));

        // Reading all contacts 
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts.."); 
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();        

        for (Contact cn : contacts)
        { 
            String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
            // need a listAdapter her
            display.setText(log + " last one");
            // Writing Contacts to log 
        Log.d("Name: ", log); 
        }

         //  db.delete_byID(0); starts at 0
         us.delete_byPhonenumber(2286719584);
         //  db.deleteAll(); delete all contacts in the table
         //  us.deleteALL(); delete the main user in the table
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Phone-numbers should be stored using a String (or a representative type).

The reason for this is the fact, that in some countries (like here in Germany) phone numbers can have leading zeros. If you use an integer to store them, those leading zeros will be gone.

Also, since you don't want to calculate with the numbers, using `VARCHAR` (in MySQL) or `TEXT` (for SQLite) seems to be the better idea.